# HttpWebRequest giving "target machine actively refused" error

Tags: proxy, httpwebrequest, pac

I am trying to access a URI through HttpWebRequest and am getting the "target machine actively refused" error.

I know from a machine that has no proxy this works fine and i know my corp internet uses a PAC file to determine the proxy however it doesnt seem to be picking this up for me.

Here is what i know:

- My app.config has
- I presume i dont need to specify WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy but that makes no difference
- I can explictly set the proxy with WebProxy and NetworkCredentials which works

Any ideas? Anybody have experience with PAC files and why I can access the target through IE but not through code. obviously if i hardcode the proxy it all works so it would seem that this same proxy is not being auto detected?

Comment: That should have read my app.config has defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true"

Comment: Well i have made progress of sorts, if i query the PAC file given a destination URL i am returned the correct proxy, I can then use the default network credentials against that and it all works fine. However i cant see why this is necessary, or does a PAC file cause issues because a proxy is unknown until a URL is given and thus HttpWebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy and similar is unable to work properly?